# Example of script in a Google Sheet to take entries and Create a calender event

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

Is there any way of adding a script to a Google spreadsheet to take info from certain fields on a sheet and add them to my Google calendar as an event.
E.g. The dates and times and an event title?

Comment: Yes.  It can be done.  How much programming experience do you have?

Comment: Hi Sandy- I have no programming experience. Im interested to try make this work. So far I have been able to copy the script from google developers and change the calender to the default and run rhe script. The example shows lines if text as the entries. So all I need to know now us giw to change the text in ' ' marks to a specific cell on the sheet the script is run on and tgen how to implement that like an add on on tge sheet so tgat once I enter data to the sheet I can hit a run addon and post the relevant data to tge calender entry!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom menu to your spreadsheet that will trigger the code to run when you choose a menu item.

Add an `onOpen()` simple trigger function to your code that will create the new menu when the spreadsheet opens:

### Code.gs

```
function onOpen() {  //Runs when spreadsheet is opened

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      //Run a function named fncAddToCalender when menu item is choosen
      .addItem('Display User Dialog', 'fncAddToCalender')
      .addToUi();
};
```

### Function that originally runs from menu trigger:

```
function fncAddToCalender() {
  var arrayOfData = fncGetData(); //Runs the function that gets the data
  fncAddCalenderEvent(arrayOfData);  //Runs the function that adds the calender event
};
```

### Function to get Data:

```
function fncGetData() {
  //Get data from Spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];  //Get the first sheet, index zero
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 10, 3);  //Get a REFERENCE to a range of cells
  var values = range.getValues(); //Get the values out of the range
  return values;  //Sends data back to the function that called this function
};
```

### Function to add Calender Event:

```
function fncAddCalenderEvent(argDataToAdd) {
  //Code to add calender event

};
```

Comment: Thank you Sandy. i am very grateful, i will try out this and see how i go...wish me luck, you have been very helpful.thankyou